# Step to create a facebook app to send new posts to a my own page in php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I can't find a usefull guide online.

I know i need to create an app from developer fb page, but i don't know what fields and permission i need.

I need to post new articles to a my own page using php.

I read about graphapi page to request token pages but documentation is very bad!

Any suggest how to start with the correct app creation?

Answer (score 1):

For you to create an application using Facebook SDK, you will need to install its dependencies with PHP SDK. THis [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/) tutorial, should help you achieve this goal.

Once you have done that, there are some guides and articles that might help you start your own development of application, that you can access using the below links.

1. [How to Develop Facebook App with an Example using PHP SDK](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/develop-facebook-app/)
2. [FacebookApp for the Facebook SDK for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookApp/5.0.0)
3. [Facebook SDK v5 for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the links, my doubt is about creating app from developer fb page. Where i need to indicate manage_pages and others privileges. I know i need to retroeve a longlive access page token but in my trying i failed, cause i don't find a usefull tutorial how to create app from dev page

Comment: Hi @itajackass is something like mentioned [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52750/how-do-i-make-a-developer-app-on-a-facebook-page-account), what you are looking for? If not, could you please clarify the `create app from dev page`?

Comment: Hi, from this page https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ to get permission for my php script... Or i wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to create an account there, to be abel to become a Facebook Developer.

Comment: Yes i have already an account. I don't know what setting i need to set for facebook app when i click ADD NEW APP